# Render Canvas Only works in an open window?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, canvas, render

I got a little problem im confused with.
I'm drawing some  WPF Canvas  in C#  and adding them to a list. I Bind the list to a TabControl to Show them. I can see all fine. So now i want to save them all as PDF i create for ea Canvas an separate PDF. The First PDF shows the Canvas the others are all empty. 
If I Open ea Canvas in the Printing method in a new Window with ShowDialog() and close it than it creates all Pages fine.

So how can i Render all without open an extra Window, which need to be closed.

Im Using [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/MainPage.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) for Creating PDF's

//PDF Creating methode

```
 s_document = new PdfDocument();
            s_document.Info.Title = "PDFKlemmen";
            s_document.Info.Author = Environment.UserName + " FESTO AG & Co. KG Abt. SG-ME";
            s_document.Info.Subject = "Belegungsplan IO";

            //cCanvastest ct = new cCanvastest(Can); // This is the other Window
            //ct.ShowDialog();

            PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage page = s_document.AddPage();
            page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A372;

            RenderTargetBitmap bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)(1114 / 72 * dpi), (int)(1584 / 72 * dpi), dpi, dpi, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);//PixelFormats.Pbgra32/ 72 *300
            bitmap.Render(Can);
            BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmap));


            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage() { CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad };
            System.IO.MemoryStream outStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            encoder.Save(outStream);
            outStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            bmp.BeginInit();
            bmp.StreamSource = outStream;
            bmp.EndInit();



            XImage image = XImage.FromBitmapSource(bmp);

            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

            gfx.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, 1088, 1584);
            gfx.Dispose();
            image.Dispose();
            outStream.Close();

            //ct.Close();
            s_document.Save(sPfadTemp + "Klemme" + Nr.ToString() + ".pdf");
```

Comment: Please edit your title to reflect your *actual* problem more closely.

Comment: Better? I close now the Window with a timer automatically but is there no solution without open a window?